# BulkWriteError - MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I understand this error occurs because of _id duplication in my code. I'm writing an aggregation pipeline where there are no unique fields in _id and I guess that's where duplication occurs. I want to either insert duplicate _id (which I suppose I can't) or create unique _id object.

I tried using BSON.ObjectId() to generate unique id with insert_many() but it says it cannot encode object: {ObjectId('5d4a71227e16ce9599a8d6ac')}, of type:

```
col.aggregate([{
    '$project' : {
        'date' : {'$dateToString' : {'format' : '%Y-%m-%d', 'date': 
        {'$dateFromString': {'dateString': '$createdAt'}}}},
        'cinemaid' : 1,
        'planid' : 1,
        'location' : 1,
        'creditworth' : 1,
        'amountpaid' : 1,
        'upsize' : 1
    }
}, 
{
    '$group' : {
      '_id' : {'location' : '$location', 'cinemaid' : '$cinemaid', 'planid' : 
      '$planid', 'date' : '$date',
      'credithworth' : {'$sum' : '$creditworth' },  
      'addons' : { '$sum' : '$amountpaid'}, 
      'upsize' : {'$sum' : '$upsize'}  
    }
}])
```

I expect each aggregated document either with unique _id or duplicate _id to be inserted into collection.

Comment: How are you doing the `BulkWrite()` and have you tried `upsert:true`. Please update that in the question itself.

Comment: I use insert_many() to insert all aggregated documents into collection. I tried collection.save() but it says "to_save must be an instance of dict, bson.son.SON, bson.raw_bson.RawBSONDocument, or a type that inherits from collections.MutableMapping"